# How to use a variable from another class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I just have a (hopefully) simple question. How do I make a variable in one class that can be accessed by another class in Kotlin?

Class A:

```
var isBlue = 1
```

Class B:

```
if isBlue==1 then ...
```

Comment: You need to reference an instance of the other class and use `.` dot notation to access its properties. `someInstanceOfA.isBlue == 1`.

Comment: I'm guessing you are very new to OOP? Please post the code you wrote so far!

Comment: I have no written code yet. I am just trying to make some sort of switch that determines which functions I'm gonna run in the other class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

class A

```
class A {
    var isBlue = 1
}
```

class B

```
class B {

    var classA = A()

    fun demo(){

        classA.isBlue//get A member
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

you can either create an instance of the object and access the property like this

```
ClassA().isBlue
```

or inherit the class and access the attribute like this.

```
ClassB:ClassA{ fun someFn(){if (isBlue == 1) do something}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java , just declare with " static " , no need to call class name , in Kotlin need to call class name , but null pointer exception , Such headache problem