# Cancel all Previous Api call in Android - Retrofit - Using module

Tags: android, api, networking, retrofit, okhttp

I have created below **module** in my android application.

```
val appNetworkModule = module {
// Dependency: OkHttpClient
single {
    var okHttpClient=OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(get<Interceptor>("LOGGING_INTERCEPTOR"))
        .addInterceptor(get<Interceptor>("OK_HTTP_INTERCEPTOR"))
        .build()
  }
}
```

Now, I have to clear all the previous api calls while doing Logout from the app.
So, I need to access the variable used in here as above named : **okHttpClient**

I am trying to access it as below to cancel all the previous api calls in my main activity:

```
appNetworkModule.okHttpClient.dispatcher.cancelAll()
```

But, **okHttpClient is not accessible**.

What might be the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59161582/how-to-use-a-variable-from-another-class-in-kotlin

Comment: @UsamaAltaf Please see it carefully. I have not used class. It's module in kotlin.

Comment: Sorry I am not into kotlin but I think you can create another method in your module like `single` create cancelAll and call your function in it and then call your method from class like you are calling `single`

Comment: @UsamaAltaf I am not calling it, it's a functionality of koin dependency library.

Comment: the point to inject this client in some classes, for instance in ViewModel. But not having a reference for the object from a module. It's not how DI libs work

Answer (score 1):

I might be late here, but the correct answer is that since it is defined in the module (Provided that you are using koin as a DI library). We need to inject it in our required class (where we need to call the `okHttpClient`) either using a constructor injection or using a field injection.
So our code will be something like this.

**Using Construction Injection**: Make sure your Class `TestClass` gets the injected `okHttpClient` for example define the `TestClass` in the **module** like this `single { TestClass(get()) }`

```
class TestClass(private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient) {

 fun clearAllApis(){
   okHttpClient.dispatcher.cancelAll()
 }
}
```

**Using field injection**: If you need to use field injection instead

```
class TestClass {

private val okHttpClient : OkHttpClient by inject() //If it is extended from Android platform class like AppCompatActivity, Fragment etc. or a KoinComponent extended class
private val okHttpClient : OkHttpClient by inject(OkHttpClient::class.java) //Otherwise

 fun clearAllApis(){
  okHttpClient.dispatcher.cancelAll()
 }
}
```

Make sure `.inject()` is from `org.koin.android.ext.android.inject`